# Microsoft Azure VPS - has no IPv6

Tags: ipv6, azure, vps

I have VPS on Microsoft Azure server. I need to redirect one AAAA DNS record to my VPS but I cant find any IPv6 address. Is it possible to generate IPv6 from IPv4 or how can I find it?

Here is the picture from Azure admin. All I have is IPv4.

[image]

Comment: I didn't need it. All I have to do was delete the AAAA record in my DNS admin. Now only IPv4 works.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you are not able to change your current NIC to allow IPv6, so you must either redeploy your VM or attach a new NIC IPv6 and delete the old one. Also all SKUs for public IP (IPv4 and IPv6) must be Standard. Don't forget to keep save your VM's disks to avoid any mistake. All steps to achieve this configuration are below.

I suggest you to test it in staging before changing your production.

1 - configure an address space IPV6 for your VNET
[address space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyIKg.jpg)

2 - configure your current subnet where this VM lives to allow IPv6
[subnet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SovFr.jpg)

3 - Your NIC looks like as this picture. Configure both IPv4 and IPv6 for this NiC.
[nic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orn2T.jpg)

4 - Your VM shows up both IP (IPv4 and IPv6)
[vm information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mpB1.jpg)

Comment: I didn't need it. All I had to do was delete the AAAA record in my DNS admin. Now only IPv4 works. There was a problem with certificate for domain which did not match IPv6 from my DNS provider.